# Trim any zeros at the beginning of a string using PHP

Tags: php, trim

Users will be filling a field in with numbers relating to their account.  Unfortunately, some users will have zeroes prefixed to the beginning of the number to make up a six digit number (e.g. 000123, 001234) and others won't (e.g. 123, 1234).  I want to 'trim' the numbers from users that have been prefixed with zeros in front so if a user enters 000123, it will remove the zeroes to become 123.

I've had a look at trim and substr but I don't believe these will do the job?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use [`ltrim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php) and pass the characters that should be removed as second parameter:

```
$input = ltrim($input, '0');
// 000123 -> 123
```

`ltrim` only removes the specified characters (default white space) from the *beginning (left side)* of the string.

Answer (score 2):

```
ltrim($usernumber, "0");
```

should do the job, according to the [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/ltrim)

Answer (score 1):

```
$number = "004561";
$number = intval($number, 10);
$number = (string)$number; // if you want it to again be a string
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always force PHP to parse this as an int.  If you need to, you can convert it back to a string later

```
(int) "000123"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can drop the leading zeros by converting from a string to a number and back again. For example:

```
$str = '000006767';
echo ''.+$str; // echo "6767"
```

Answer (score -3):

Just multiply your number by zero.

```
$input=$input*1;
//000000123*1 = 123
```

Comment: Why simply not convert that string number into an actual number?

Comment: Multiplying by zero does not give the same answer as multiplying by one. Maybe it's time to review some elementary school maths books.